# Building REST services with Jersey

Tags: jersey

I am trying to upgrade my REST web services from 1.17.1 to 1.19, and it is a mess as am struggling to get the build right. With no changes to any source whatsoever, the services are not coming up with multiple error messages every time.

Here is the **pom.xml** of my project

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>API</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src,resources</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>   
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.0.M2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here is the error when i start the Web Service.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet CcxAPIs threw exception
>           org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>           org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> root cause
>       com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
>           com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:509)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:339)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
>           com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
>           javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>           org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
>           org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>           org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1437)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Am I missing anything here? I'm sure many should have faced these issues. Please help with suggestions to fix this.

Comment: can you share your web.xml

Comment: Please leave the rant out next time. It's just unnecessary noise.

Comment: Have you google this "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes?" There are hundreds of similar questions on SO.